# Error bound for function limit with arbitrary $\Delta h$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

Say we have some function $f\in C^1$. I would like to somehow bound the error that is made when the limit is approximated using some arbirary $h$, that is to find $E(x,h)$ such that:
$$|f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}|\leq E(x,h)$$
where $h$ is some specific number (i.e. $h=0.01$). I do not recall any helpful theorem but I'm really rusty on my analysis so please, bear with me if it's totally obvious.

**2nd part**

What if on the other hand I wanted to find $E'(x,h)$ which entails: 
$$|f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}|\leq E'(x,h)$$
I remember that two-sided limit is more precise so is it the case that $|E(x,h)|\geq|E'(x,h)|$ ?

Comment: Since $f$ is $C^1$, $f'$ is locally bounded.  Then, you could use the mean value theorem on the difference quotient.

Comment: Thanks Michael. You mean like this:
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq f'(c) $ for some $c \in (x,x+h)$ ?

Comment: It's actually an equality, not an inequality.